# Bind variable "D" not declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, sqlplus, urbancode

I am trying to run a sql file in sqlplus. This sql file simply adds a package and some stored procedures to the database. It is written using the specification/body separation convention. However, it appears that the package declaration part is problematic, leading to the body part failing. In fact, I am not sure if the "Binding variable" part is even relevant. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Dec 20 11:41:36 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> set timing on;
SQL> set exitcommit off;
SQL> 
SQL> REM Output Log
SQL> REM All script output is SPOOLed here.
SQL> REM Recommend not to change or use SPOOL in other locations
SQL> REM If you do break the spool chain, then consider using SPOOL APPEND to reestablish
SQL> 
SQL> PROMPT ------------------------------------------------------------;
------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> PROMPT PROCESSING: D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\Create_table.sql;
PROCESSING: D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\Create_table.sql
SQL> PROMPT ------------------------------------------------------------;
------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> PROMPT COMMAND: @"D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\Create_table.sql" ;
COMMAND: @"D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\Create_table.sql"
SQL> TIMING START;
SQL> @"D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\Create_table.sql" ;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    L_CNT PLS_INTEGER;
  3    lv_stmt varchar2(32767);
  4  BEGIN
  5    --Check if the table already exists
  6    SELECT COUNT(0)
  7    INTO L_CNT
  8    FROM ALL_TABLES T
  9    WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = 'DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE'
 10        AND T.OWNER = 'IT';
 11    IF L_CNT > 0 THEN
 12       dbms_output.put_line('The table already exists');
 13      RETURN;
 14    END IF;
 15  
 16    --Check if the constraint already exists
 17    SELECT COUNT(0)
 18    INTO L_CNT
 19    FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
 20    WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'DEVOPS_UC_Server_Reg_PKEY'
 21        AND C.OWNER = 'IT';
 22    IF L_CNT > 0 THEN
 23       dbms_output.put_line('The primary key constraint already exists');
 24      RETURN;
 25    END IF;
 26  
 27    dbms_output.put_line('Creating table...');
 28  
 29  
 30    /*
 31   this code is auto-generated from DBMS_METADATA. It was accessed using the following query:
 32  
 33  SELECT
 34  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TABLE','DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE','IT')
 35  FROM DUAL;
 36  
 37   so long as the tables do not exist, and the PRIMARY KEY NAME does not already exist
 38   then this will create the table with the primary key constraint.
 39   otherwise, you will run into ORA-0095: name already used by existing object (if table exists)
 40   or ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
 41   TODO: make the table name and primary key constraint name variables for ease of use/robustness
 42  */
 43    lv_stmt:=q'[
 44    CREATE TABLE "IT"."DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE"
 45     (    "AGENTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 46      "SERVERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 47      "DATELASTDEPLOYED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE,
 48      "TECHNOLOGY" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 49      "ISSETUP" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
 50       CONSTRAINT "DEVOPS_UC_Server_Reg_PKEY" PRIMARY KEY ("AGENTNAME", "SERVERNAME", "TECHNOLOGY")
 51    USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
 52    STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 53    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
 54    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 55    TABLESPACE "IT"  ENABLE
 56     ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
 57    PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 58   NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 59    STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 60    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
 61    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 62    TABLESPACE "IT" ]';
 63  
 64      execute immediate lv_stmt;
 65  dbms_output.put_line('Table created successfully');
 66  
 67  END;
 68  COMMIT;
 69  PROMPT ;
 70  PROMPT STATUS: SUCCESS;
 71  TIMING STOP;
 72  PROMPT ;
 73  PROMPT ------------------------------------------------------------;
 74  PROMPT PROCESSING: D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\UC_Server_Reg.pck.sql;
 75  PROMPT ------------------------------------------------------------;
```

I believe the issue probably stems from these lines and below:

```
 76  PROMPT COMMAND: @"D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\UC_Server_Reg.pck.sql" ;
     77  TIMING START;
     78  @"D:\ucd-agent\var\work\devops.urbancode.db.ServerRegistry-OracleScripts\1.0.0.31-a23aaeb-workdir\IT\UC_Server_Reg.pck.sql" ;
     78  create or replace package it.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REGISTRY is
     79  
     80  
     81  PROCEDURE RetrieveUCServerRegTable
     82  (
     83            RC1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     84  );
     85  
     86  PROCEDURE ExtraStoredProc
     87  (
     88            RC2 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     89  );
     90  
     91  PROCEDURE ExtraStoredProc2
     92  (
     93            RC2 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     94  );
     95  
     96  PROCEDURE InsertUCServerRegistryEntry
     97  (
     98      inAgentName IN VARCHAR,
     99      inIsSetup IN VARCHAR,
    100      inServerName IN VARCHAR,
    101      inTechnology IN VARCHAR
    102  );
    103  
    104  end;
    105  /
    SP2-0552: Bind variable "D" not declared.
    Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
    SQL> 
    SQL> show errors
    No errors.
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REGISTRY AS
      2  
      3  PROCEDURE RetrieveUCServerRegTable
      4  (
      5            RC1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
      6  
      7  )
      8  IS
      9  BEGIN
     10    OPEN RC1 FOR
     11         SELECT *
     12         FROM it.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE ;
     13  END RetrieveUCServerRegTable;
     14  
     15  PROCEDURE ExtraStoredProc
     16  (
     17            RC2 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     18  
     19  )
     20  IS
     21  BEGIN
     22    OPEN RC2 FOR
     23         SELECT *
     24         FROM it.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE
     25         WHERE agentName='appsrvdev11.otpp.com';
     26  END ExtraStoredProc;
     27  
     28  PROCEDURE ExtraStoredProc2
     29  (
     30            RC2 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     31  
     32  )
     33  IS
     34  BEGIN
     35    OPEN RC2 FOR
     36         SELECT *
     37         FROM it.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE
     38         WHERE agentName='ucdagentdev01.otpp.com';
     39  END ExtraStoredProc2;
     40  
     41  
     42  PROCEDURE InsertUCServerRegistryEntry
     43  (
     44      inAgentName IN VARCHAR,
     45      inIsSetup IN VARCHAR,
     46      inServerName IN VARCHAR,
     47      inTechnology IN VARCHAR
     48  )IS
     49  
     50  BEGIN
     51  
     52  MERGE INTO IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE
     53    USING DUAL ON (IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE.agentName = inAgentName AND serverName = inServerName AND
     54               technology = inTechnology)
     55   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     56     UPDATE SET DATELASTDEPLOYED = SYSDATE,
     57            isSetup = inIsSetup
     58   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     59     INSERT( agentName, isSetup, serverName , TechnoLOGY, DATELASTDEPLOYED)
     60       VALUES( inAgentName, inIsSetup, inServerName, inTechnology, SYSDATE );
     61  
     62  
     63  END InsertUCServerRegistryEntry;
     64  END ;
     65  /

    Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

    Elapsed: 00:00:00.45
    SQL> show errors
    Errors for PACKAGE BODY IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REGISTRY:

    LINE/COL ERROR
    -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    0/0  PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
    1/17     PLS-00201: identifier 'DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REGISTRY' must be
         declared

    1/17     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REGISTRY'
         without its specification

    SQL> COMMIT;

    Commit complete.
```

Comment: Both errors seem to stem from whatever is happening before line 78, i.e. in the code you haven't shown us... probably another PL/SQL block that isn't terminated properly?

Comment: Sure, I didn't think it was relevant but I will add it now just in case. I am certain the other code before line 78 is correctly formatted (tested it independently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 67  END;
 68  COMMIT;
```

You need a slash on a line on its own to terminate (and execute) the anonymous PL/SQL block, between the `END;` (which is the 67th line of the anonymous block) and the next statement, the `COMMIT;` in this case (which is not part of the anonymous block and so should get its own `SQL>` prompt in the output too).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the issue!